# How do I see what OSX app is capturing my keyboard combo?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion

It seems since the Lion upgrade CMD-left/right arrow is being captured by something.. This is a keyboard shortcut in my IDE and I miss it dearly.. How do I figure out what is capturing that keyboard shortcut and make it stop?

Comment: Found http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17944/home-and-end-commands-in-lion, might help.